# WordPress Ignoring My Custom Post Type Templates?

Tags: custom-post-types, template-hierarchy, theme-roots

WordPress is 404ing all of my Custom Post Type posts. Have I missed a step here?

I’m using the following to set up my CPT:

```
function custom_post_types() {  
  register_post_type(
    'creativework',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x('Works', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Work', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Work'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Work'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Work'),
        'new_item' => __('New Work'),
        'all_items' => __('All Works'),
        'view_item' => __('View Work'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Works'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No Works found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Works found in Trash'), 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => __('Works')
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'menu_position' => 5,
      //'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'work'),
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
      'has_archive' => 'true'
    )
  );
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_types' );
```

I originally had an underscore in the type (`creative_work`), rewriting the slug to just be “work”, but I had no idea which permutation WordPress would use to find the template—I tried file names like `single-creative_work.php`, `single-creativework.php`, `single-work.php`, all under `themes/roots/` (I was using [Roots](http://roots.io) as a baseline theme), with the contents:

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/content', 'work'); ?>
```

But `themes/roots/templates/content-work.php` was never displayed. Instead it seemed that `themes/roots/page.php` was being served up? When I manually edited `page.php` to `get_template_part('templates/content', 'work')` as a test, it seemingly used the template I wanted but then it had the post ID or something wrong where it was displaying the homepage for ANYTHING under `website.com/creativework/`.

In an attempt to eliminate all possible conflicts, I deactivated Roots in favor of Twentythirteen, and disabled all plugins except one, the one I wrote to set up the CPT (code at the top). Now, whenever I hit `website.com/creativework/` or `website.com/creativework/post-title` (following the permalink from “View Work” in the post editor, or in Search results), I get a 404 instead of the homepage, despite both `single-creativework.php` and `archive-creativework.php` existing under `themes/twentythirteen`.

**EDIT:** `website.com/?creativework=post-title`, however, works.

I am hopelessly confused by all this. What is the correct, foolproof way to set up a custom post type template, step-by-step? Ideally I want to know how to do this in Roots, but for now I will settle on just how to get it working at all.

Comment: have you flushed rewrite rules since adding the custom post type?

Comment: I have now. No luck.

Comment: AHA, I had tried to use `flush_rewrite_rules()` on plugin activation/deactivation, but that didn’t seem to do anything. When I changed the permalink structure and saved it, then it worked! If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. I had tried to use `flush_rewrite_rules()` on plugin activation/deactivation, as so:

```
function creativeworks_activate() {
  // register taxonomies/post types here
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function creativeworks_deactivate() {
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'creativeworks_activate' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'creativeworks_deactivate' );
```

…but that didn’t seem to do anything. However, when I changed the site-wide permalink options arbitrarily and saved them, then the rewrite rules were flushed successfully, and my custom post type templates started working again.

Thonks to Milo for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: having these sort of problems with roots zoo but refreshing permalinks via the admin or above works.

Comment: THANK YOU for posting your solution.  My problem was a little different (WP ignoring single-{post_slug}.php template.  Resaved permalinks and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the arguments of register_post_type that can be causing problems in the frontend. This argument:

```
 'has_archive' => 'true'
```

Should be:

```
 'has_archive' => true
```

The correct filename for the single template of your custom post type (creative_work) is `single-creative_work.php` and **should be in your theme folder**. For example, if your theme is called "my_theme", the file `single-creative_work.php` should be in `wp-content/themes/my_theme/single-creative_work.php`. You can also include template files from differents locations using [template_include()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) function.

The folder structure you are talking about is not the usual in Wordpress (`roots/lib/`, `roots/templates/`, etc). Are these folders from a plugin?

Comment: They are from the Roots theme. (http://roots.io).

Comment: My answer is still valid, you should put template files like `single-*.php` in the top folder of the theme. The files inside the folder `roost/templates` are not really templates files, they are files with code that will be inserted into several templates (those files are template parts).

Comment: I already tried that though; as I said in the OP, creating `roots/single-creative_work.php` seems to have no effect. (`roots/` is the theme folder.) I keep getting the homepage.

Comment: So, you have a custom post type `creative_work` and the template file `single-creative_work.php` is not used if you put this file in the top level folder of your theme. Can you try to register the post type like `creativework` (without the _) and then use single-creativework.php?

Comment: I did that, even replacing all instances of "creative_work" with "creativework" in the database, and it still isn't displaying. On top of that, I deactivated the Roots theme (switching to Twentythirteen) and all plugins (except for my own "Creative Works" plugin, which just sets up the custom post type), and now, instead of seeing the homepage, I get 404s, both for `website.com/creativework/` and `website.com/creativework/title-of-post`. I have `single-creativework.php` and `archive-creativework.php` under `twentythirteen`.

Comment: See my edited answer. I think you get 404s because an error in the arguments of `register_post_type()`.

Comment: Wouldn't that evaluate to true anyways? (depending on if they explicitly check for bool var type!) sorry just being difficult

Comment: Yes, but, if I remember correctly, `'true'` (string) will generate the slug `true` for the archive URL (i.e. `example.com/true`, while `true` (bollean) will autogenerate the slug based on post type name.

Answer (score 0):

I also use roots and I have a small workaround (not really pretty but for me it keeps things organized). In the root of the template directory there's a `single.php`. There you can put:

```
if(is_singular('creativework')){
    get_template_part('templates/creativework', 'header');
    get_template_part('templates/creativework', 'main');
}
```

Then you'd put `creativework-header.php` and `creativework-main.php` in the templates directory.
I use this method because I have several custom post types and this way I can use my own naming instead of having a lot of `single-cptname.php` files. I actually deleted all contents of single.php and put the above function (and some more for each post type) there. Next to that, I can include multiple template parts per custom post type (some have up to 5). This keeps my stuff way better organized!

PS, are you sure the name of your custom post type is `creativework` and not `creative-work`?